# FINDING OF protocol of a device using ipaddress

Tags: java

I want to know how to find the protocol(SNMP,TL1,CLI,HTTP) being used by a targed device using its ipaddress

Is there any code to find out...if so pls tell

I will be thankful to your valuable replies

Comment: what are you looking making a scanner ? " find the protocol(SNMP,TL1,CLI,HTTP) being used by a targed device using its ipaddress" what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to try to open a TCP connection to the IP address using the port numbers of each of the protocols you are interested in.  It is called port scanning, and it is likely to get you unpopular if you do it without permission!

P.S.  the value of this answer 2 cents :-)

Comment: @Stephen: I am generous 20 cents!

Comment: It is also necessary to actually exchange data on each port in order to detect which protocol is actually running on it.  Protocols tend to have default ports defined in their specs, but devices are not required to use those ports.  Many servers use non-standard ports due to firewall/router configurations and such.